# SQL Query on special conditions

Tags: sql, db2

Please help me to form the SQL query...
I have a table in DB2 i.e. SVA1ARTICLE,

TABLE NAME:

```
SVA1ARTICLE
```

Table having the column

```
ID
KEYWORD1
KEYWORD2
KEYWORD3
KEYWORD4
```

Requirement:

1. Need to find out the KEYWORD which is at least repeated 100 times from all 4 individual KEYWORDS COLUMN i.e. also UNIQUE. for ex. budget is the keyword in COL KEYWORD1 and repeated 100 times then result will return budget. same applies with other KEYWORD field.
2. From result return from the above query we need to find out all the column from same table. i.e. if above query return 'budget' as keyword then, we need to find out all the record which having keyword budget and gives us the first 50 latest rows.

Please help your warrior who is the frontier with sword only no extra ammunition in hand.

Thanks,
Gladiator

Comment: I tried for 1 point but how to achieve second I still dont understand.. for the first, select KEYWORD1 from SVA1ARTICLE group by KEYWORD1 having count (KEYWORD1) > 100;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree zxq9 post. You need to normalize your database. Middle time:

"Normalized" data:

```
create view SVA1ARTICLE_N
as
   select ID, keyword1 as k
   from SVA1ARTICLE union all
   select ID, keyword2 as k
   from SVA1ARTICLE union all
   select ID, keyword3 as k
   from SVA1ARTICLE union all
   select ID, keyword4 as k
   from SVA1ARTICLE
```

> "Find out the KEYWORD which is at least repeated 100 times from all 4
>   individual KEYWORDS COLUMN"

```
create view key_100
as
   select k
   from SVA1ARTICLE_N
   group by k
   having count(*) > 100
```

> "From result return from the above query we need to find out all the
>   column from same table. i.e. if above query return 'budget' as keyword
>   then, we need to find out all the record which having keyword budget
>   and gives us the first 50 latest rows."

```
select distinct id
from SVA1ARTICLE_N
where k in (select k from key_100)
```

This query returns ID for rows that match your criteria, be free to complete your self the query getting last 50 rows from SVA1ARTICLE source table.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion your are modeling the data in a difficult way.

It would be easier to make a  KEYWORD table with a ForeignKey from SVA1ARTICLE, and a reference constraint that the same SVA1ARTICLE cannot be referenced more than 4 times from the KEYWORD table.

If you do this, your query logic becomes *much* simpler, the query speed will be increased (create an index on KEYWORD for both the stored word and the reference to SVA1ARTICLE), and you wont be stacking lots of sub queries to get your result which will be very difficult to adjust later when the spec changes to handling, say, 3 or 5 keywords (or unlimited, which is impossible on your existing model).

With new model, how your problems would be handled:

1. With a separate KEYWORD table, you can just pull a simple query where occurrences of the word exceed whatever threshold (in this case 100).
2. From the result of #1 above, you can just pull a simple query of all articles having the >100 word(s).

You can do this as a single query (#2) with a subquery (#1) or in the application as building an initial data list from #1, and then making a second query #2.

Until you adjust your data model answering this question in detail with code is not really practical.

Comment: I understand but my problem is that, this table very old in the system having millions of row and I am not authorize to create new tables so need to do everything with this table only....

Comment: I wouldn't take the job if I wasn't allowed to convert it... but that aside. You will need to make a long multiple-query to build a giant list. Connect the results of SELECT SVA1ARTICLE, KEYWORD1 AS keyword FROM table; with the same query from KEYWORD2~4. If you sort this list on "keyword", you can locate the place where occurrences > 100. Every unique SVA1ARTICLE from that point on is the list of SVA1ARTICLEs you want. I hope that made sense. Hard to explain in an unformatted comment.

Comment: If I am not misunderstanding then connecting the result means, I need to UNION for all the four query.

Comment: Yes, UNION ALL, to be specific. Just UNION will eliminate duplicates, but you *want* duplicates in this case because your intent is to count them. The giant UNION ALL query needs to be a subquery to an aggregate counting function, or a sort and then count, or whatever works best in DB2, really. So then you can eliminate everything that is < 100 occurrences (or whatever your threshold is for counting), and the unique remainder are the terms you want to form your new query against.